# Remove drive Q microsoft office click-to-run 2010 (protected)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, virtual-drive

There is no trace of Microsoft office on my computer and I don't think there has been for more than 5 years, but just today there appeared a drive Q labeled microsoft office click-to-run 2010 (protected). I can't remove it. All the answers on answers.microsoft seem to think that either uninstalling microsoft office will remove it or that you simply can't remove it. I'd appreciate anyone that can tell me why it's there or how to remove it.

If you try to click on the drive you get a message "Please insert a disk into Microsoft Office Click-to-Run 2010 (Protected) (Q:)."

[image: Unwanted/unexplained drive]
[image]
[image: MS office is not on my machine]
[image]

Comment: What are drives O P and R?  A card reader per chance?  If you right-click on the Q: drive and look at it's properties, what kind of device does it report itself as?

Comment: They are different media drives for flash or sd camera cards. I added a picture from the drive properties. There aren't actually any usb devices plugged in.

Comment: That drive is created my office software as you previously stated, try installing revo unintaller and see if office populates in that list. http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html

Comment: It wasn't there yesterday and I haven't had Microsoft Office since the day I opened the box on the computer. Is there any reason it would appear now?

Comment: Some sites are recommending to remove "Microsoft Application Virtualization Desktop Client"  so have an eye for that aswell in Revo. I see that its not in your cpanel list.

Comment: Maybe a windows update... or some other software you installed... not sure.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see Microsoft Application Virtualization Desktop Client. I don't see it under services. Where do I find it?

Comment: Look for Client virtualization in services and disable it, then reboot. Microsoft Application Virtualization Desktop Client would be in the programs list.

Comment: I don't see either Client virtualization or Microsoft Application Virtualization Desktop Client in the services or programs lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure its one of your card reader slots that's Q:, it's just labelled wrong due to Office being previously installed.

You should be able to change its label by heading into the registry to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons\Q`, and then editing the `(Default)` setting in the `DefaultLabel` sub key.

Not sure why it would suddenly show up again, unless you just added the card reader, or perhaps disabled "Hide empty drives in the Computer folder" in Explorer's settings.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I checked by inserting media into each until I figured out which one. Then I did like you said and updated the registry key. Thanks. You are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **"USE AT YOUR OWN RISK"** solution.
Download the Click-2-Run removal tools from KieSeyHow's skydrive below
http://sdrv.ms/11hV2PR

1. Unzip package
2. Run offcln.exe
3. Reboot
4. Run CleanC2R.exe
5. Reboot

I ran the exe's on my win 7 comp without issues.
I also scanned them for viruses, they are clean.
That being said, they are not verified and supported by microsoft, so **use at your own risk**.

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c82f8ba2-d84a-4167-9117-d650a1899bb0/unable-to-uninstall-clicktorun?forum=officesetupdeployprevious

Comment: Why not just use the official Office removal tools available through Microsoft?

Comment: Yeah, that's also worth a try.

Comment: There's an official office removal tool? Where?