# Remove drive Q from my computer?

Tags: windows-10, storage

I have drive Q in My Computer. It's slowing everything down and I would like to remove it. After researching a little, I found that Microsoft Office Click-to-run can be the cause of this. I have Office 2013 installed. But I searched the whole computer for traces of Click-to-run and it's not there! So apparently there's another cause for it. How can I remove this drive?

EDIT: Here's a screenshot:
[image]

EDIT2: I just discovered that after removing it using the reg file below, everything became faster in my computer. If your right-click takes a long time often, you *must* do this, and you'll thank me :)

Comment: `net use q: /delete`?

Comment: @DavidPostill It's not a network drive (I'll add a screenshot). It's a local drive! That didn't work.

Comment: Do you see it in Disk Management? Can you set it offline?

Comment: @AtomicFireball Nope... it's not on Disk Management.

Comment: I think its likely related to office, but it could be another application. The Q: drive is used for "Application Virtualization Technology" a safe location where virtualized applications can store there data. Is office starter installed?

Comment: @mt025 I agree. The problem is that there's no indication on anything related to office click-to-run or starter. If I go to programs and features, there's only "Microsoft Office 2013 Pro Plus", Office 2013 "Correcting helper" (roughly translated from German "Korrekturhilfen") and "Visual studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime x64". I don't know what I could do to remove it or even know what is causing it, but likely it's something related to office...

Comment: Q drive is by design for Click to Run. I learned something today! See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982434

Comment: @AtomicFireball Actually I learned the same thing today before posting this question :) . But I don't see any option to uninstall it!

Comment: So if you uninstall the Office Click To Run from the Add/Remove Programs, it will be removed after rebooting your computer. This means uninstall Office then uninstall Click to Run. http://www.ghacks.net/2011/11/25/how-to-remove-the-office-2010-starter-virtual-drive/

Comment: You cannot remove it unless all Click to Run apps have been removed because it's essential for it to operate.

Comment: @AtomicFireball :(

Comment: @AtomicFireball Btw, Click-and-run is not on the programs and features list, and hence I can't do what's mentioned in the blog.

Comment: Looks like it's been answered here before. See if the solution in this answer works. http://superuser.com/questions/1105816/remove-drive-q-microsoft-office-click-to-run-2010-protected

Comment: @AtomicFireball Unfortunately I don't have any other drives inserted...

Comment: I see an R and S drive in your screenshot? Did you have a Q previously?

Comment: @AtomicFireball drives R and S are network drives that I added and I regularly use. Q, is local with no local driver associated with it. I don't remember when it came up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google search [shows you this solution from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/931626):

Copy/paste this into a .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoDrives"=dword:00010000
"NoViewOnDrive"=dword:00010000
```

and import it via double click.

Comment: and does it work? or not?

Comment: I need some more time. Solutions that require restarting are not that simple for my case. I'll come back to you soon. Thanks :)

Comment: Didn't work... I tried both with "Explore" (as written) and "Explorer".

Comment: it should work according to Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/931626 make sure you set the type (decimal/heximal) correctly

Comment: Of course I checked decimal and hexadecimal. But it just didn't work... I don't know why! I wanna add that the key "Explorer" wasn't there, and I had to add it.

Comment: use the .reg file that MS provides in the KB article.

Comment: OK. That reg file works, but your steps are incorrect; there's an entry missing (see the reg file to know what I'm talking about). Thanks for the link, as it contained the solution. Instead of the steps, please copy/paste the reg file from that KB article, and I'll choose this answer. Thanks again.